# Duplicate entry with cakePhp

Tags: cakephp, orm, duplicates, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to apply data by adding _copy to the name and of course a new ID but I am not at all expert cakePHP and I do not know where to start. Here is my view:
I add the button "duplicate" with a route in the controller

```
<td>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(
                'Dupliquer',
                array(
                    'controller' => 'contracts',
                    'action' => 'duplicate',
                    $contract['Contract']['id']
                ),
                array(
                    'class' => 'btn btn-default btn-sm'
                )
            ); ?>
        </td>
```

The function I call in my controller:

```
public function duplicate($id = null) {
        if (!$id)
        {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Identifiant invalide'));
        }

        $contract = $this->Contract->find('first', [
            'conditions' => [
                'Contract.id' => $id
            ]
        ]);

        if (!$this->Contract->HasAny(['Contract.id' => $id])) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Le contrat n\'a pas pu être trouvé'));
        }

        $data = [
            'name' => $contract['Contract']['name']. '_copy',
        ];

        return $this->redirect('edit');
    }
```

In my function I retrieve the information to duplicate and it is here that I stuck at the level of the recording. Do you have an idea how to do it to make it clean?

Thank you.

Comment: Is your goal to create a duplicate entity that just gets saved to the database immediately, or to open an edit page that defaults all the values to a copy of the original, and it only gets saved if the user then clicks "Save"?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$contract = $this->Contract->findById($id);
```

to:

```
$contract = $this->Contract->find()->where(['id' => $id])->first();
```

then:

```
$data = [
  'name' => $contract->name. '_copy',
  // other fields ...
];

$entity = $this->Contracts->newEntity($data);
$this->Contracts->save($entity);
// ...
// $this->redirect($this->referer());
```

Comment: Why not `findById`? (Though `->first()` should be added to it.) But surely just `->get($id)` is even simpler yet?

Comment: What are you thinking about?

Comment: Error: Call to a member function where() on array :s

Comment: @GregSchmidt I think most developers avoid "magic finder methods". Method "get($id)" is OK, but CHRISCOM use own  Exceptions.

Comment: @CHRISCOM typo fix